# asp.net mvc generic controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, generics

I am thinking of implementing a generic Controller in ASP.NET MVC.

```
PlatformObjectController<T>
```

where T is a (generated) platform object.

Is this possible? Is there experience / documentation?

One related question for example is how the resulting URLs are.

Comment: You would have to configure routes for each `T`... or perform some lookup magic at runtime. There are performance implications to this, but other than that, it seems like it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

yes it is, you just can't use it directly but you can inherit it and use the childs

here is one that I use:

```
     public class Cruder<TEntity, TInput> : Controller
        where TInput : new()
        where TEntity : new()
    {
        protected readonly IRepo<TEntity> repo;
        private readonly IBuilder<TEntity, TInput> builder;


        public Cruder(IRepo<TEntity> repo, IBuilder<TEntity, TInput> builder)
        {
            this.repo = repo;
            this.builder = builder;
        }

        public virtual ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            return View(repo.GetPageable(page ?? 1, 5));
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(builder.BuildInput(new TEntity()));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TInput o)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(o);
            repo.Insert(builder.BuilEntity(o));
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
    }
```

and usages:

```
 public class FieldController : Cruder<Field,FieldInput>
    {
        public FieldController(IRepo<Field> repo, IBuilder<Field, FieldInput> builder)
            : base(repo, builder)
        {
        }
    }

    public class MeasureController : Cruder<Measure, MeasureInput>
    {
        public MeasureController(IRepo<Measure> repo, IBuilder<Measure, MeasureInput> builder) : base(repo, builder)
        {
        }
    }

    public class DistrictController : Cruder<District, DistrictInput>
    {
        public DistrictController(IRepo<District> repo, IBuilder<District, DistrictInput> builder) : base(repo, builder)
        {
        }
    }

    public class PerfecterController : Cruder<Perfecter, PerfecterInput>
    {
        public PerfecterController(IRepo<Perfecter> repo, IBuilder<Perfecter, PerfecterInput> builder) : base(repo, builder)
        {
        }
    }
```

the code is here:
http://code.google.com/p/asms-md/source/browse/trunk/WebUI/Controllers/FieldController.cs

**update:**

using this approach here now: http://prodinner.codeplex.com

Comment: Ok - so my problem is solvable. 
If the type for the type parameter is generated, and the base controller is generically implemented, all I need to do is to generate the derived controller for each type that I want to use as type parameter. That's as simple as can be.
Cool!