# How to create a generic controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult SaveEdits(MagHeader viewModel) {
        AppRepository.SaveData(viewModel);
        return PartialView("DisplayForModel", viewModel);
    }
```

The ViewModel is very simple and just holds a few properties.

```
public class MagHeader {
    public string MagDate { get; set; }

    public string MagTitle { get; set; }

}
```

This all works just fine.  However, the issue is that I have about 40 of these different viewmodels and a controller action for each.  All it's doing is saving the data properties of each which I can do through reflection.

Is there a way to have one controller handle all of them?  They are all string properties so really they are just key/value pairs.  Is there some way to make the controller action generic?

Comment: see if this helps...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009031/how-to-use-asp-net-mvc-generic-controller-to-populate-right-model

Comment: Well, I read over the link as well as quite a few other ones, and I don't see a way of doing what I wanted which was to type the controller actions at runtime based off a string.

Comment: IMHO, best option is to create a binder (IModelBinder) and instead or receiving a MagHeader or other, receive a Dictionary<string, string>.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  If you want to post this as answer (with maybe a brief example) I will accept it.