# Generic<T> ActionResult with children of T which is not generic type

Tags: c#

I refer to the second answer from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009031/how-to-use-asp-net-mvc-generic-controller-to-populate-right-model).

I wrote something like this in my project:

```
public class DetailsViewModel<T> where T : Standard
{
   public IList<T> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{}

public class InitialStandard : Standard {}

public class AlteredStandard : Standard {}

public class InitialDetailsViewModel : DetailsViewModel<InitialStandard>
{}

public class AlteredDetailsViewModel : DetailsViewModel<AlteredStandard>
{}
```

Then I have two methods to whom I refer to one ActionResult:

```
public void DetailsInitial(long Id)
{
    Details<InitialDetailsViewModel>(orderId);
}

public void DetailsAltered(long Id)
{
    Details<AlteredDetailsViewModel>(orderId);
}

public ActionResult Details<T>(long Id) where T : DetailsViewModel<Standard>
{
    var model = Mapper.Map<T>(order);
    return model;
}
```

How to use this method with `DetailsViewModel` children, if they are not generic?

I remark that difference in mapping is in profiles for `InitialStandard` and `AlteredStandard` classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure, but I think you are looking for this:

```
public void DetailsInitial(long Id)
{
    Details<InitialDetailsViewModel, InitialStandard>(orderId);
}

public void DetailsAltered(long Id)
{
    Details<AlteredDetailsViewModel, AlteredStandard>(orderId);
}

public ActionResult Details<T, U>(long Id) 
    where T : DetailsViewModel<U> 
    where U : Standard
{
    var model = Mapper.Map<T>(order);
    return model;
}
```

Here, you say that `T` inherits `DetailsViewModel<U>` where `U` inherits `Standard`.