# Implement a custom controller factory ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was reading a post about custom controller factory ASP.NET MVC.

Someone explained but I just do not understand how to implement. Here is the post URL
[In asp.net mvc is it possible to make a generic controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848904/in-asp-net-mvc-is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-controller?rq=1)

They said

> You would like `/Product/Index` to trigger `MyController<Product>.Index()`

This can be accomplished by writing your own IControllerFactory and implementing the `CreateController` method like this:

```
public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
{
    Type controllerType = Type.GetType("MyController").MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(controllerName));
    return Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType) as IController;
}
```

Need a bit more sample code. Just do not understand where to define `CreateController` function. Do I need to write this function in base controller?

When request comes like `/Product/Index` or `/Customer/Index` then how index method can be invoke in base controller?

So looking for guidance for a newbie like me in MVC advance area. thanks

Comment: In the answer, it derives from DefaultControllerFactory. For this question, you  got to implement IControllerFactory. Deriving from DefaultControllerFactory won't help.

Comment: DefaultControllerFactory will also work. The code shown did not have an override, So assumed it requires IControllerFactory. Both methods will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to implement [IControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) (or inherit from [DefaultControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which contains some extra functionality). After that, set your controller factory in `Application_Start` by using [SetControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460275%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

Hope this clarifies things a bit for you.

Comment: can u redirect me to any article for  IControllerFactory interface. thanks

Comment: @Thomas IoC is one of the best examples of using custom controller factories. This article may help you: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/117/Dependency-Injection-and-Inversion-of-Control-with-ASP.NET-MVC

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to create a class that implements the
   [IControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) interface.
2. You can ignore the ReleaseController method.
3. You can return SessionStateBehavior.Default for the GetControllerSessionBehavior method.
4. In Application_Start, set the Custom ControllerFactory as follows:

   ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CCustomControllerFactory));

Comment: can u redirect me to any article for  IControllerFactory interface. thanks