# Can not access a controller (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This controller:

```
public class TestController <T> : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {             
        return "123";
    }
}
```

This definition of the routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Default",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new
     {
          controller = "Test<T>",
          action = "Index",
          id = "" 
     });
```

This is the error I get:

> The IControllerFactory 'Yad2.Web.Mvc.UI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Test'.

Comment: How come you are using a generic controller? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Generic controller???  Show how are you configuring Ninject.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestController <T>   : Controller
{
    public string Index( )
    {             
        return "123";
    }
}
```

List of things wrong here:

1. Controllers cannot be generic abstract classes, you need to define **T**.
2. All actions need to return **ActionResult** derived objects.
3. "Test" in your route definition is **absolutely** incorrect. Never going to work.
4. You never showed your Ninject registration.

Comment: Agreed with everything but 2. You can return `string` or `bool` from Action Result methods.

Comment: There is a way to use a Generic controller.. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848904/in-asp-net-mvc-is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-controller

Comment: @krillgar it isn't advised you do so, if you want to do that use the Content() method in the controller.

Comment: @NitinMidha The controller in the link you sent me is a generic controller where **T** is defined. It is not defined in the above code. Essentially this user wants to magically pull a generic type out of thin air. You can't do that unless you build a mechanism to set **T** dynamically and create it (maybe using route values). MVC will not resolve **abstract** controllers.