# Can you use generic methods in a controller?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to have a generic method in a controller? I'm talking about something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void DoSomething<T>([FromBody] SomeGenericClass<T> someGenericObject)
    {
        SomePrivateMethod<T>(someGenericObject);
    }
```

I have actually tried the above (though with different names for everything) and posted to `Api/<controllername>/DoSomething` with the instance of `someGenericObject<T>` in the request body, and it didn't work (i.e. it didn't reach the controller).

I'm guessing that Web API routing is not able to resolve generic methods since they may result in different methods for different types underneath. But that's just what I think.

So, is it possible to have a generic method in a controller?

- If yes, how?
- If not, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In asp.net mvc is it possible to make a generic controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848904/in-asp-net-mvc-is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-controller)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Sort of" is the answer here. With generics, you must eventually define the underlying type *somewhere* and at *some point* or else it's all just theoretical. How would Web API or MVC route the data in your request (which is just QueryString GET or FormData POST key-value pairs) to a generic type **and automatically infer the intended type**? It cannot. What you could do is make a private generic method on the controller, but have the Action Methods of the controller resolve to concrete types which are passed to the private generic method.

You could also [take a look at this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/849072/2420979) as an alternative, convention-based approach. It should work pretty well for you assuming that you are specifying the concrete type of your generic controller as part of the URL, QueryString, or FormData.

Comment: Your first suggestion is what I originally had in mind, but I wanted to see whether generic controller methods were actually possible. I thought Web API could just use the name of the method but I understand that it actually matches the querystring/body data to the parameters as well, and that's impossible with generics.

Comment: @Gigi not impossible. It just requires you to specify the concrete type in some fashion and interpret it. A custom controller factory looking for the concrete type as part of the URL, QueryString, or FormData would work, though feels a little "hacky" to me.

Comment: Yes, it's overkill for what I need. I can just specify a method per type, and use generics internally.