# Generic Controller Action Methods

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, url-routing

Is it legal to have controller action methods that are generic? For example, I made this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class NumbersController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("{orderType}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create<T>(
        [FromBody]
        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(OrderModelBinder))] 
        Order<T> order) where T : IOrder
    {
       //....
    }
```

My custom `OrderModelBinder` checks the {orderType} path segment to determine the concrete `IOrder` used to create the `Order<T>`.

When I run the code, I get a 404.  I am not sure if it is because I've done something wrong, or if ASP.NET simply does not support this.

Perhaps instead of a custom model binder, I should use a custom IActionInvoker?

I'm working with both ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Web API 2.x.  I suspect if this can be done at all, it will be a similar technique either way.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848904/in-asp-net-mvc-is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-controller) Generic Controller SO question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thank you for the link, but an `IControllerFactory` won't help in this case because it is my action-method that is generic, not the controller  (and I don't want the controller itself to be generic).