# Call generic method with type from javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, generics, razor

Can't seem to find any example on how to call generic method with type from javascript using ajax

```
    public virtual JsonResult GetData<T>(SomeClass firstParam) where T : class, ISomeInterface
    {
       ...
    }
```

Call with ajax

```
    ...
    ajax:
        {
            url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "Controller")",
            type: "POST",
        },
    ...
```

Edit 1:
Just to clarify duplicate report. I'm trying to call generic method not controller so something like this

```
 ...
    ajax:
        {
            url: "@Url.Action<SomeClass>("GetData", "Controller")",
            type: "POST",
        },
    ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In asp.net mvc is it possible to make a generic controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848904/in-asp-net-mvc-is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-controller)

Comment: See edit 1 for duplicate clarification