# C# register controller using custom IApplicationModelProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I was working on defining generic controller for my web application, similar to the one [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848904/in-asp-net-mvc-is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-controller). The difference is that, in my case, controller routing prefix can contain one (ie: */Person*), two or (more general) *n* segments (ie. */hr/Employee*, ...). The answer from [Jeff Fritz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29156/jeff-fritz) suggested that custom `IControllerFactory` should be implemented.  However, since my routing structure is pretty complex and, therefore, hard to implement using `RouteAttribute` or `MapRoute` function in `Program.cs`, provided custom `IControllerFactory` was not called and, thus, not working. I have seen that controller could be registered using custom `IApplicationModelProvider` implementation. I was wondering how should a generic controller be registered for it to contain all `actions`, `properties`, `filters`, `route values` and `selectors` as expected by the default `IApplicationModelProvider` implementation?

Comment: Have you checked this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#modify-the-controllermodel-description)?

Comment: @XinranShen I am currently lookung it up (to be more precise, I think I'll go with implementing my own `IControllerModelConvention` and providing custom `IApplicationFeatureProvider`) - I think it'll be both easier and cleaner than providing my own `IApplicationModelProvider`. Thanks for advice.